# How to get a pixel color from a screen with the defined max color depth?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, screen-scraping

Clickermann has function ColorMode(n).

Functionality:
The procedure modifies the current screenshot by applying a filter to it that reduces the number of colors in the palette

I want do the same thing with C#.

I need to get a pixel color from screen according to max color depth because it must work with regions with a lot of similar colors (for example gradient)
[image: Original color depth]
[image: Max color depth = 8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Creates an empty bitmap with the size of the current screen
Bitmap screenshotBitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
// Creates a new graphics object that can capture the screen
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshotBitmap);
// Draw a screenshot on the bitmap
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, screenshotBitmap.Size);
// Clone bitmap and make it 4 bit
Rectangle screenshotBitmapRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, screenshotBitmap.Width, screenshotBitmap.Height);
Bitmap screenshotBitmap4BitPerPixel = screenshotBitmap.Clone(screenshotBitmapRectangle, PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed);
```

And do everything you want with bitmap

```
screenshotBitmap4BitPerPixel.Save(@"C:\Users\FreePhoenix\Desktop\Bitmap.bmp");
```